# Why isn't my array getting fully populated?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, user-input

I have created a method in which I create an empty array that can hold 6 integers. Then I run a for-loop which will ask the user for an integer, verify it as a positive integer and then send that integer to be stored into my array.

```
public static int[] populateArray() {
int[] cupsPurchased = new int[6];
// Create a Scanner object to read user input
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Use a for-loop to prompt the user to enter each month's data.
    for (int i = 0; i < cupsPurchased.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter the cups purchased " + (i+1) +" month(s) ago " + ": ");
        int cups = scanner.nextInt();
        
        // Validate the input to ensure it is a positive integer
        while (cups < 0) {
            System.out.println("Error: Cups purchased must be a positive integer.");
            System.out.print("Enter the cups purchased " + (i+1) 
            +" month(s) ago " + ": ");
            cups = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        
            cupsPurchased[i] = cups;

        // Prompt the user if they want to enter more data
        if (i < cupsPurchased.length - 1) {
            System.out.print("Do you want to enter the cups 
           purchased for another month? (Y/N) ");
           String answer = scanner.next();
            if (!answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                break;
                }
             } else {
               break;
            }
           }
    
    return cupsPurchased;
    
   }
```

The problem seems to be that my for-loop won't take my first integer entry (1 month ago) and send it to my array. Every other integer entry seems to work just fine.

Comment: When posting code here, take some care with line-wrapping and indenting. Somehow you broke lines of comments and of strings. I fixed some of it for you.

Comment: if you want to iterate over every index in an array you do. for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++), you did  for(int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++). What you did makes sure the for loop never reaches the last index. If you want to use for(int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) you need to add the <= instead of < so that the for loop reaches the last array index. Remember java arrays are 0 based numbering. so its either for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)  or for(int i = 0; i <= array.length - 1; i++)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is here: `if (i < cupsPurchased.length - 1)`.

When `i` equals `cupsPurchased.length - 1` you reach the second `break`. So the final item, namely the 5th, is never read from input.

Comment: So in the part where I ask the user if they want to enter the data again, I got rid of the else statement. I thought too many breaks may hamper with my code. 
And do you suggest that I get rid of the -1 over there?

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer by vahidreza](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75513786/642706) is correct. In addition, I can show you how to simplify your code. We can avoid the kind of mistake that tripped you up.

Break up one long procedure into separate methods. Each logical chunk of work can be in its own method.

- `inputCupsPerMonth` to ask for each month’s number of cups.
- `askToContinue` to ask if the user wishes to continue.

Also, naming variables can make the code more clear.

```java
package work.basil.example.cups;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cups
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        Cups cupsApp = new Cups();
        int[] cupsPerMonth = cupsApp.inputCupsPerMonth( 6 );
        cupsApp.report( cupsPerMonth );
    }

    private int[] inputCupsPerMonth ( final int countMonths )
    {
        int[] cupsPerMonth = new int[ countMonths ];
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
        for ( int index = 0 ; index < cupsPerMonth.length ; index++ )
        {
            int monthsAgo = index + 1;
            cupsPerMonth[ index ] = this.askForCups( monthsAgo , scanner );
            if ( ! this.askToContinue( monthsAgo , scanner ) )
            {
                cupsPerMonth = Arrays.copyOf( cupsPerMonth , index + 1 ); // Truncate array.
                break;
            }
        }
        return cupsPerMonth;
    }

    private int askForCups ( final int monthsAgo , final Scanner scanner )
    {
        System.out.print( "Enter the cups purchased " + ( monthsAgo ) + " month(s) ago " + ": " );
        int cups = scanner.nextInt();

        // Validate the input to ensure it is a positive integer
        while ( cups < 0 )
        {
            System.out.println( "Error: Cups purchased must be a positive integer." );
            System.out.print( "Enter the cups purchased " + ( monthsAgo ) + " month(s) ago " + ": " );
            cups = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        return cups;
    }

    private boolean askToContinue ( final int monthsAgo , final Scanner scanner )
    {
        return true; // Replace with own code to prompt user for permission.
    }

    private void report ( final int[] cupsPerMonth )
    {
        System.out.println( "cupsPerMonth = " + Arrays.toString( cupsPerMonth ) );
    }
}
```

When run:

```
Enter the cups purchased 1 month(s) ago : 7
Enter the cups purchased 2 month(s) ago : 42
Enter the cups purchased 3 month(s) ago : 3
Enter the cups purchased 4 month(s) ago : 4
Enter the cups purchased 5 month(s) ago : 5
Enter the cups purchased 6 month(s) ago : 66
cupsPerMonth = [7, 42, 3, 4, 5, 66]
```